# How can I set up TinyMCE so that it won't allow inline data images?

Tags: image, filter, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE installation on a CMS and the users have been pasting in images which are of the inline data type. This kind of thing:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/
/ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcpp
V0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7" 
width="16" height="14" alt="embedded folder icon">
```

They are pasting in some pretty large images, and the content gets stored in a database. This is making the database grow very quickly in size, and there is already a media upload component available, so how can I simply prevent the editor from accepting this type of image?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you want.
Due to the fact that you won't be able to disallow this kind of element using valid_elements and child_elements you will have to go other ways.

**Case 1**: You do not want user to enter this kind of image onPaste.

You will need to use the paste plugin and set the parameter paste_pre

```
paste_preprocess : function(pl, o) {
    window.console && console.log('Object', o);
    window.console && console.log('Content:', o.content);

    // modify o.content here -> remove images of that kind
    o.content = o.content.substr(...)
}
```

**Case 2**: You want the images to be filtered out before they are getting saved into the DB.

You may use the tinymce [setup paramter combined with onSave](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onSaveContent) to get rid of them.

From what you describe you seem to be wanting Case 1.

Comment: The other case (#3) would be when a user drags an image into the editor as well. Firefox (and some other browsers) convert the image to a data URI as well.  This isn't caught by the paste_preprocess callback.  There is an option `paste_block_drop` that can be set to `true` that will stop drag and drop of images, but unfortunately it also drops dragging and dropping content within the editor. Tiny MCE 4.x has a new option to prevent data URIs.