# Firefox crashes on element.remove()

Tags: firefox, tinymce

When tinyMCE is used with Firefox and the user drags an image into the editor,image.remove (); window FF converts the image to a base64 string and embeds the image as text--not optimal DB strategy. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573474/how-can-i-set-up-tinymce-so-that-it-wont-allow-inline-data-images/27137576#27137576) addresses the issue. I've added a simple handler to the editor that handles it simply:

```
if (tinymce.isGecko) {
editor.getDoc().addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    var image = event.target;
    if ((image.nodeName === 'IMG') && (image.src.substring(0, 30).match(/.*?data.*?;base64/g))) {
        image.remove ();
        alert('Using drag-and-drop for images with Firefox has been disabled for technical reasons. Please use the "Add Media" button.')
    }
},
false);
```

}

But image.remove (); crashes Firefox every time. Can anyone verify this, and is there a workaround?

Comment: if you can crash FF consistently with some (simple) JS code, you should report it immediately the FF devs. it may not be exploitable, but would be a trivial DoS attack vector for FF users.